# On xib, dragging view will automatically go inside a bigger view

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, interface-builder, xib

In my xib I have one UIView and one UIImageView. 
The UIView covers all the xib, the UIImageView one is much smaller. If I drag the UIImageView, it snaps automatically inside the view.

It drives me insane because I never want that. I just want to change its position and the only way I can do that is from the Utilities/Size Inspector. But is very frustrating when I have a lot of objects and I can't use drag & drop to move things around.

Is there a way to prevent/disable this, please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to **uncheck** the `installed` checkbox of larger view while you are moving/adding another view

[image]

Comment: Yeah, that's what I do now, it's the only thing that works, but imagine I have a lot of views and not all of them are installed on all size classes. Is hard to remember which one should be installed on certain size class, so I quit doing this.

Comment: Hmmm that true, may be someone else has the nicer solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can do that with use of click on size inspector. 
First you can select UIImageView and then goto the size inspector and change x and y.

Comment: Yes, I said I can do that. But I want to be able to use drag & drop, I spend a lot of time using size inspector.

Comment: can you explain in detail

Answer (score 0):

You can use arrow keys on your keyboard or set it in `size inspector` pane.

Comment: I know, but it takes a lot of time to move an object for more than a few pixels.

Comment: When you hold shift and your arrow key, it allows you to jump by 5 pixels.